# Sharepoint 2013 list of teamrooms I have access to

Tags: sharepoint-2013

How to see teamrooms I am member of in Sharepoint 2013?
I do not remember names - am a member of multiple rooms. There are hundreds of teamrooms, so full list is of no help unless I use a whole day clicking on each of them.
I remember in Sharepoint 2010 there was such a possibility, a nice small list of rooms I have been invited to and used previously. Or is it probably dependent on installation. Hopefully just a specific link exists, which is unfortunately not added to any pages.
Another point - I have not followed any teamrooms, so that list is empty for me.
As well, my AD account has no hints of access groups for Sharepoint, it is administered in Sharepoint internally. Of course, I have no admin rights there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to get with your Admin or Site Administrator.  You can create a list using Search.  they can either use the Content Search, Search Results WebPart, or create a vertical in existing Search Center.

With any of these you can create a rule that only targets team sites.  Search will security trim this list so site you dont' have access too won't show up in the results.

Comment: Search would help if we didn't have hundreds of unrestricted teamrooms. But, yes, the admin asking way looks like the only kind of solution, but depends on their priorities.

Comment: Looks like the admin contacting is the only way towards a solution. Fortunately I do not need Sharepoint anymore. It was more PITA for users and admins than a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it has been a straight migration from 2010 to 2013 all the old sites/teamrooms and associated permissions will still be there.

You could try manually entering the URL into the address bar in your browser. Alternatively, if you click the "sites" link at the top of the SharePoint page to the left of your name it lists all the sites you have access to.

If it is a fresh installation it is perfectly possible that the permissions and access rights to the sites have not been set up. If that is the case you will probably need to contact your SharePoint administrator.

Comment: What is the typical UR (last part, of courseL, to enter manually? Sites link gives an empty list of Sites I'm following and Suggested sites to follow. Nothing usable there.

Comment: It is sounding like your SharePoint administrator has revoked your access to the sites either intentionally or accidentally. The URLs will be completely unique to your organisation, I couldn't possibly guess at them. You should probably speak to your IT department.

Comment: I don't expect link to any specific teamroom, but the list of them. Accesses are not revoked, as few rooms I have direct links to, but not all. None of rooms are on any one list. So I was hoping there was a Shp default link to such list. Especially when there was such one in Shp 2010, looked quite generic, but unfortunately I do not hold such info in memory :)